# Method only applicable on single Instance of Class instead of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I have Class `items` which holds the fields `mProductType` amongst some other.

Inside this class there is the following method:

```
public ArrayList<Item> getProductsByCategory(String category, ArrayList<Item> productList) {

    ArrayList<Item> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {

        if (productList.get(i).getmProductType() == category) {
            returnList.add(productList.get(i));
        }

    }
    return returnList;
}
```

So far so good. In my other Class `ProductsInCategoryFragment` i try to call the method like this:

```
ArrayList<Item> products;

// ... filling variable "products" with content
products = fetcher.getItems();

// ... declaring the category String
String category = getArguments().getString("CATEGORY");


products.getProductsByCategory(category, products);
```

I can call the method from an instance of the class item but not on an ArrayList of that class. That last line of code gives me this error:

```
Error:(82, 17) error: cannot find symbol method getProductsByCategory(String,ArrayList<Item>)
```

I know this may be a very basic question but i just can't seem to get the hang of it. Is this some kind of visibility problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this signature and implementation it could rather be a `static` function, as it does not use any members from a current (`this`) object. `ArrayList<Item> products` is, well, an `ArrayList`, not your `Item` type, that is why it does not have your methods. Plus, comparing `String`s with `==` does not work in general, use `equals()` instead.
So:

```
public static ArrayList<Item> getProductsByCategory(String category, ArrayList<Item> productList) {

    ArrayList<Item> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {

        if (category.equals(productList.get(i).getmProductType())) {
            returnList.add(productList.get(i));
        }

    }
    return returnList;
}
```

use as:

```
ArrayList<Item> filteredItems = Item.getProductsByCategory(category, products);
```

(Assuming that `getProductsByCategory()` is a method in `Item`, but there might be a better place for it, perhaps somewhere near your `main()`, or wherever you plan to use it)

Answer (score 1):

It should be `items.getProductsByCategory(category, products);` You try to call `getProducts...` method on an `ArrayList` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom `ItemList<Item>` class extending `ArrayList<Item>`. In this class you can add the `getProductsByCategory` method. Afterwards change your products variable to `ItemList<Item> products;`

```
class ItemList<Item> extends ArrayList<Item> {

  public ArrayList<Item> getProductsByCategory(String category) {
    ArrayList<Item> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this; i++) {
      if (this.get(i).getmProductType().equals(category)) {
        returnList.add(this.get(i));
      }
    }
    return returnList;
  }

}
```

Or in Java 8 you could simple use streams to filter the list based on category, and you won't have to implement your own getProductsByCategory function.

```
List<Item> result = products.stream()
                            .filter(p -> (p.getmProductType().equals(category)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```